# Can't import jdl using jhipster

Tags: jhipster

**strong text**I am using JHipster v6.5.0. My blueprint is generator-jhipster-vuejs. My database is Postgresql. I have been working to this jhipster project for around 2 months. Today I updated my jdl and since then I can not import it using this command `jhipster import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh`. It says `INFO! No change in entity configurations, no entities were updated.` I also tried  `jhipster import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh --force`. it says

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

    at rewrite (C:\Users\0568\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster-vuejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\utils.js:117:38)
    at Object.rewriteFile (C:\Users\0568\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster-vuejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\utils.js:63:18)
    at Object.addEntityToRouterImport (C:\Users\0568\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster-vuejs\generators\utils.js:136:19)
```

I also tried to import previously imported jdl but could not import them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have updated JHipster before the vuejs blueprint has been updated, the required changes were merged 7 hours ago in https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-vuejs/pull/493/commits/c849040e2fa932ce96dd0385fe994a8e91d6db63 and have not been yet released.

Now you have to wait for next vuejs blueprint release, use a local clone on master or use JHipster 6.4.1

Next time before updating JHipster, check which version is supported by the blueprint in the release notes at https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-vuejs/releases or in package.json.

Comment: I have downgraded jhipster to 6.4.1 but still, it is showing the same error. Also used --force. But no luck!

Comment: Are you sure that the local version of the generator is 6.4.1? Sometimes, users upgrade or downgrade global version and forget about the project's copy.

Comment: I checked my project's copy. It's "generator-jhipster": "^6.4.1", global version is also 6.4.1 and blueprint is  "generator-jhipster-vuejs": "1.1.0",
Only the json files are created in .jhipster folder with an additional property  "readOnly": false,

Comment: The version of the blueprint compatible with JHipster 6.4.1 is 1.2.0, so 1.1.0 cannot work, please update it. See https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-vuejs/releases/tag/v1.2.0

Comment: I downgraded jhipster to 6.1.2 and it works perfectly fine. Thank you so much for your help. Next time I will be more careful about updating the version.
Is there any way to make jhipster project compatible with Internet Explorer. I tried with babel-polyfill 6.26 but no luck.

Comment: I am facing another problem. When I import the jdl file, jhipster generates angular code rather than vuejs code. I tried to link vuejs blueprint and jhipster using npm link but nothing happens. Every time I try to import jdl it always generates angular code. Please help!!

Comment: Please open a new question